# Couchbase view sharing between buckets

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

We are a group of developers where everybody has their own bucket - but the same views.

I'd like to have one file with views defined under source control.

This file shall then be somehow easily applicable to existing bucket so that views on this bucket would be updated.

How can I easily achieve that?

Comment: Try not to add signature. Read FAQs!

Comment: sorry. have no idea what you mean... what is signed there? maybe i'm not clear enough - we have more developers, each one has it's own bucket. now somebody needs to either create or modify existing view. How to now update other guys buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved with help of

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/couchbase-view#comment-1007530
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-designdoc-api.html

simply i keep my view definitions in files and through couchbase rest api i update the view in couchbase. so any time developer needs to update their bucket, they run simple tool which goes through folder with views and these are updated...

Comment: It really helped me to export views from one bucket and import into another bucket easily. Thanks.